# Decode hex response from scapy TCP packet

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

Hi I'm trying to capture network incoming traffic and make reason of the data returned from a server.

Here is an example:

```
{
"Ethernet": {
    "dst": "e0:e0:e0:e0:e0:e0",
    "src": "d4:35:1d:15:2d:46",
    "type": "IPv4"
},
"IP": {
    "version": "4",
    "ihl": "5",
    "tos": "0x80",
    "len": "140",
    "id": "8738",
    "flags": "DF",
    "frag": "0",
    "ttl": "106",
    "proto": "tcp",
    "chksum": "0x8883",
    "src": "66.66.66.666",
    "dst": "192.168.1.228"
},
"TCP": {
    "sport": "4451",
    "dport": "51604",
    "seq": "1848896275",
    "ack": "3094121781",
    "dataofs": "5",
    "reserved": "0",
    "flags": "PA",
    "window": "513",
    "chksum": "0xa76c",
    "urgptr": "0",
    "options": "[]"
},
"Raw": {
    "load": "'P\\uf77b\\\\xddH\\x06\\\\xeb_\\\\x9e\\\\xe3G\"\\x19\\\\xbd\\\\xb8\\\\xe7m\\\\xe6\\'\\x00#\\\\x9a\\\\xe3\\\\xf9Y9$\\x07\\\\xda-\\\\xa7\\\\x9fb\\x18u\\\\xd1W\\\\xafdK3\\\\xf8\\\\x96f\\x08\\\\x8a\\x0c\\\\x96\u4920\\\\xa8\\\\x88niF\u0296F\\\\xd3) \\\\xe2%i\"2-\\rQ\\x128\\x1e\\\\xce8B\\\\x86\\\\xb1\\\\xb6\\x11\\\\xd4\\x132\\\\xf3KI\\x0et\\x1d\\\\xc9\\\\xe4\\\\xf4\\x7f\\\\x976\\\\xe50\\x00\\x00'"
}
}
```

I'm trying to print the Raw -> load in various of methods but I get nothing....
any Idea how I can convert this to human readable string?

I have tried : `str(parsed_packet['Padding']['load'])` also `hexdump(parsed_packet['Raw']['load'])` and even `bytes(parsed_packet['Raw']['load'], encoding='utf8')`

Nothing gives me any results I get the same load spitted at me or some gibberish.

**EDIT:**
The capture data is just an attempt to investigate why I cant read or decode the TCP data that is returned from a server that serves and old application written in java - I can successfully connect to the server and send the required data but when the server streams back and expected XML I cant decode it - I know its not using encryption it simply looks as its compressed.

here is all the data:

```
target_data = [b'\x00\x00\t\xc5\x00\x00 \x00x\x9c\x95Ymo\xdb8\x12\xfe\xee_\x11\xa0\xc0~J\x1c\x8a\x92H*X\x1f\x104\xe9\xa2\x80\xb7]\xd4\xb9\xdd\xbbC\x01A\xb1\xe9X[Y2$9\xd9\xec\xaf\xbfy(\xc9\x16i\xa6\xf5\xba\xd5\xc4\xe4\xbcpf8\x9c\x19\xca\xbf\xdf\xce?\xdeM>\xcf\xef\xd2\x7f/\xee\xbfL\xe6\xb7\x0f\xf7\x8b\x87\xf4\xf7\xfb/\x8b\x8f\x9f?M\x9e\xa3){\x99\xdc}\xfe\xe3\xd3\xfc\xf3\xed\x9d5\xfd:\xb9\xff\xcfo\x1f\xbf\xdc>`\x823\xce\xafX@\xff/xx\x13\'\xf4\x7f\xf2\xf0\xf1\xd7\xfbt\xf1\xdfO\xef\'\x81\x08U\x1c\x85"\x88C%\xba\xf9\xff}\xfet?\xb9\xe2J1|&?/t\xdb\xe6\xe5S\xb3xmZ\xbd\xfd\xd7\xe4\xdd\xfbZg\xad^]T\xe5\xc5\xc3^_\xdc\xee\xea\x0b\x16^\xf0\xe0&P7At\xf1\xeb\xdd\xc3\x05g\x81\x9a\xbc\xfb.v\x957\xbb"{\x9d\xee\xeaj\x97nt\xb6\xd2u\xda\xe4\x7f\xeb\x19\x9b,\xab\xa2\xaa\x9b\xe9r\x93\x95O\xba\x99\xb2\xe9\xba\xaa\xf5S]\xed\xcb\xd5\xec\x83\xf9\x9c\x92<f\xcbo=I\x92\x18\xc5\x87\x05\x9a]U\xb7\xcdcU}\x9b\x16y\xf9m\xd6\xd6{\xed\xf2\xf3\xf1\x12\x8c\xd9\xfc\x98l\xd2\xac\\\xa5Y\xa1I\x14i[\xec\xd2}]\xcc6m\xbb\xfbzs}\xddT///\xd3UU>\xea\xa6\x9d.\xab-\xcd\\w|W\x1d\xcft\xd3n\x8b\xd3UGZ3\xf6\xe1\x03;\xd8>\xf2\xcawT[We{\xa66 \xbd\x02i\xa7\xc9 a\xecx~4Y/\xabr\x95\xd5\xaf\xd6\xc6\x04>\xe5F\x16(v\x1b\xbe\x0f\x0eB\xf46\xcb\x8b\xce\xdb\xc3T\xb5"G\xbed\xedrs\xa6\xd6`0\xf4\xb6\xd6\xdb|\xb5*\xf4?\xdb\x8e\x8e\xa7\xdf\x0e\x8f\'\xbe\xe9\xd7t[=\xebs\xe5\x11\xbd!\xb7v6+Z]\x97t:\xd2\xa7l\xab\xbf\xb3sD\xbf\xdf\x96i\xa3\xdb\xfd\xee\x1f\xf8\xe2\xaa\xe3\xbb2|\xbe\xed$%tc\x85\xb8\xa3\xd2h\xbf\xee\x93\xfb\xfb\x0f\xe1@WdM\x9b\x96\xfb\xed\xa3\x1dq\xef\xcd\xc7{Z\xff\xdc7m\xbe\xce\x97Y\x9bW\xe5\xec\xfd\xfd\xa7\x07\xcaRN`yi<+\x8e\xd4\n\xcdg$\xe8\x87\xce\xd97\xb4\xd2\xd3>_i\xdb\x1b\xcf\xbanh\xd9t\xbf[\x91\xfd\xcdAJ\x031\'\x1e\xde\xef\x90(\xaeI\xd6s\xbe\xd4\xcd\xf5VC\xb3\xe6\x80\xc8\xcb\xa6\xcd\x8a\xe2j\xf5\xd8D\xc7\x93B\x1eo\x97\xfb6\xa5p8;1\xf4<W\xe0ys+;\'\x9d)\xb2#\xf6H99\xc9\xdf\xdb\x90fI\xfb\xee\tZ\'m\x05\xe7\x90\xbc\x99\xd9\xbaEF\xe8>\xa3\x1f4n\xb3\xb6\xb1\xd3\xc6\xae\xce\xcf\xces\x86\xf6\xe8\x07G\xaf\xf0\xedR\xf2\x83\x03\x9b\xd5\xcbM\x8e\xe3n\xf4\xb7\x8f\x98{\xb0\xfc5*\xb4}2v\x1b\x8a\xd3\x8f\xb3\xfd&+\xd6m\xbe\xd5gzb \xbf:\xf1\xc6&\x7f\xda\x14\xf4\xb4?\xdeH\xa8\x9c\xb6U:R}\x9d\x15\x8d\xf6i\xfe\xa6\x07\x8e\xeb9$IrL\xe9\xaf\xe9s\xae_\xce\xce\xe6\xaf\xa0\xb6\xad:\xf1\x9f\xad\x85{\x14\xde6\xfe\x84r\xa4\xf6\xad\xf9\x1c\xd4n\xb3\xc7sU\x06\xe9\xc9i\xb7uw\x02D\x04\x93\xc9\xe4\xe7k\xb7\x01;tdv/\xf6\xa1\xce/\xee\xf4\x12\xddV\x10\xdd\x84\xf2\x86\xab\x8b\x8f\x0bt[<\x98\xbc\xfb.\xb6\xab*\xcdt\xa5\xd7\xd9\xbeh\xa7m \xbb6\xcc\x99U\xde\xd9d\xf6\xb6\xe7N}\xdc\xb5E\xd3Z?\xe7\x8d^\xa5\xd4\x92\xe9\xfd\xae\x99\xae\xf3B\xcf<\xc2C\xef\x92\x91w6\xf6\xce\x8a\xd3\x8e\xf2\x8d\xa3\xe802\xaf\xb8\xc0;\xcbg\xa3\xd6\xed\xcd\xea_\xeb\xae\xa8\x18\xab\xd3\xf6u\xa7\xfb\xd3\xd47\x89\xb4\xbf\xd96\xed\xba\xa72{,\xf4j\xb6`\x03\xd2\xf1\x18a\xbe\xce\xd8e@\xff&\xa6\xd5:!\x98P\xc4\xa5\xe4W\xaa\xff\xa0~\xf8:\xfb%\x90\xe2\xf2\x17\xceB\x80\x08\xc0\x0c%\x80\x02H\x08\x04\x0c \x00\x00"\x00\x82\xe3\x89\t\x80\x13\x8c\xf8\x1e\x83&\x06', b'*\x06\x8d\xc07\x01\x81\xc2\x0c!K\x82^\x82XA\xaa\x02\x87\x02\xbf2s\x90Od!\xc3#\x01\x883\x0c\xf0\x18\xc0\x01B\x00"\x0f1\xe2 5\xf4!\xa6B\x01\x00\xce\x10r"<@F`\x8f\xc0\x10\x999\xd0F\xa0\x8d\xb0@\x0c\x92\x18C\x89o\x12\xc4\x12\xc4@\x92\x9c\x88q\x80\x10\x80\xa6 ,\xc2\xc0\xe0"<\x001\x1e\x10\xc6\xe6\x1b\x89\x8b\xcc\x03\x1c\xec\x8e\xe0\xebHB\x80y\x18\x00\xe8\x15\x90$\nj\xc4,\x06\x10\x00d\x06\\\x1a\xc3l\x08\x8e\x89.&i\x90\x1f\x03\tEc\x88\x86\xbfc\x92 \x18\x1e"\x11\x84\x11\xd8%\x81\x1d\x12XP`\t\x815\x04\xa4\nH\x11\xd8\x19\x81\x9d\x11\xb0\\@\xa0\x80\xe5BB\x08\x14\x16PX\xc2v\t\xc1\x12ZI\xc4\x85D\\H\xec\x8b\x0c\x80\xc0\x96H\x04\x87\x0c\x80\xc5\xc6H\x0e,4\x90\xd8"\x19\x9ao$TbSdd\xbeA\x1e\xf4\x930Q\xc2F\t3\xa4\x00\x02\xfaIX(\xa1\x90D\xe4H\xc4\x8bT@$\xf8\x96\xd0\x9c\x82~\n^S\xd0E!P\x15tQ\xd0EA\x17\x05]\x14\\\xa2\xa0\x90B\xd4*\x84\xad\xe2`\xe3\xe0\xe0\xe0@\x00*\xa8\xab\x10x\nQ\xa6\xa0\xb8B4)D\x99\x82\t\nQ\xa6\x10!\na\xa0`\x91Bd(i\x00\xd8\xa0\xb8', b'\x82\xe2\n\x8a+\xb8SI\xb0\xc1\xa7J\x82\r\x01\xa0\x10\x00J\x01\x8b\x13\x900\x8ex\xc3\x9f\xb0\xfbC\x12\x128:A\xec\'pt\x12\x10u\x02\x93\x12\x18\x92p3\x043\xd90\x0f\xc8\xb3\xf3 \xc67\x8a\x8ay\x80\x91\x08\x01\xa2\xcb9\x9d\x82\xb9 \x83\x08D\x001\x00Q\x01\'"\x00I\x0f\xf1RX\xcc)*\xe6\x92\x84\xcf\xc9\x00z\x08C\xaa\xd3\x83QBx\xc5\x02\x80\x08\x80\xe6\x14\x1d\x0b\x02\x18Ff(\x00$\x80\x02\x00\x07E \x01\xb0\xd1\x86\x13\x00G\x0c\xe2\x18\xc4XBAs\x05\xcd\x95\x00\xb1\x00\xb1\x001\x8cPPT\tp\x08p@]\x05}\x15\x14V\xd0X)\x03\xc0\xa6@\x0cu\x95\x02\x89\x02I\x02l\x02l\x829\xd8A^\x06\x08\x01\x88#\t\x0c\x00\x82b\x87\x00\xb0\x1cX\x8a\x98y\x12b\x08\x17&pa\x12\x9a9\xd2%\x89\xa2\x9fN\xb2>]FR\xca\xfci\xa1\xd7-e\xdf\xbf\xf4\xa8c2E\x83\xda\xff\x97\xd4t\x91]\x13\xd9%\xefc\xea\x9f\r3\xa6\xdc\xf7S\xa3N\x93\x84\x96Y1\xae`\x92\xb1\x88\xab\xa1\xb2\x1e.\xb2Cy\x1a/\xb3\xdf\xeer\xb4\xaf\xe7\\\xf5\xed\x12\xc7\xbd\xc5\x9f\'\xdeYo}\xe6\xde\xfa\xccG\xf5\xf9\x87\xd7\xe7Sno\xa3\xc2Q\xba{w\xec\xf2\x96:\xf7\xf2)\xed\x8a\xff\xa1qw8P\xd6\xfbB\xeb)\xb0\xa7\xf4(\xf8GO\xe7\xe5\xb2\xd8\xaft\x9a\x97Fsg\xc7\x8f\\\xe1Q/\xe2\xabK4\xc5\xa9\xa3\xa1\xbdm\xfd\x1dv\xd6\xbd\xd7\xc3\xe6L\xf5_\xad.WT\xe8qU\xd2G\x89e\xd5\xe2\xe2j\xf3\xff\x99=g\xe9 $`S6\xe5\x13\xdcW\xab\xf5:\xc5\xed`F7m\n\x8c\xd7q\xb8\x1d\x9a\x0f\xaf\xafL\x80\x08>\xac:x\xcb\xd0\xf6s\xdd\xbb\x96~\n*o4,\xa5\xf5cq<\x07\x84hfnk\xc6=o\xf2\xf0\xee\x8a\x0e\xc8k\x01c\xbb8~\xd3{\xbd\xeb-E\xfa\xe6r\x08\xf9\xfeow\x8e\xba\x93\xd8\xbdJ\xf2\xbe\x1a\xf4]\x19\x87wz\xfd\r\xcb\xd3\xac\r{1\xc2\x14:{\xdaS\xd7G\xd7\x00tc\x97\x8b\xe0r\x11^.\xf8\xe5\x82\x92\n\x15\xd79\xa5\xfc\x05\xa5\x16*\xff\x94\xd1\xcfz\x91r\xd26\x9a\x98\r\x0e1{H\x19\x14)5]\x13<\xa6@\x9di4=6\xa4\xccNT\xd5N\x97\xba\xb6#\xc1\xbcQ\xc5\xbb+s\x0b1k\xce\x1f8\xad\xc9.cz\xba\x7ff\x1f\xe8od\x8dbk$\xacQ2\x1aQq\x88/9\x1f3\xc7\x97T\xe6\xad\xa1\xb0\x8761\xe5\xf0\xf10\xb6FT\x1c\xc6C*c\x16+\xb3\x87\xf6:\xb1-*\xb4\xd7\t\x03[)\x07\x1d\xd9\xb2B{\xe1\xd81Pq\xc7`\x9b<rd\xdbK\xc76\xb1\xb4\x89\xa5M,mbe\x0f\x83\xd8qu\xc0\x1c\xbc\xb3Q\xcc1$\xb0\xfd-\x1d\xb4\xa3L\x98\xd8\x86$\x8epk(l\xbb\x84\xb3w\x0e\xaf\xbd\x90c\x95\xbd\xb1\xc2\xd6Y9&:\xd4\x81\x134A\xe4\x8c\x85cs\xe8\xba\xd0\r\x1c[\xf3\xc45\xc4\x1d;;&\x1c\xdb\xacHc\'\xbdBw\xc0\xdbjE\x19\xc7-f\xf6\xd9GRX\xe9\x96\x92\xb0\x9d\xf3\x87d8\xee6\x0e7\xd1\x9ef\xdc\xd2ty\xba\xa33\x99x\xe6)D\xc7\xdfn\x9a\xa1-\xeak\x8buo6\xd9kH\xd8\xa7\xc9\xd8\xea\xa4zU\x86F\xc8c7\xdeq\xf7\x08\xbb#\x18\x8b\x1e<\xd7\xff\x08q(*\xbb\xfdc\x91/\xed*\xd45lVY\x1e\xd5"\x88LG)\xdcb=\xfebb\xf3\x9b\xb2\xb3\xcd\xcb}\x8b\x82\x9f\xaf\xd7\xba\xd6\xe5\x12\xd9\xdb$\xf4\xc1\x94\xa7\x1a?[5Y\x91msk\xb7,\x8fY\x92\x9d\xdav\xa8(\x9d\xe0\xae&P\xf1MI\x0c\xbaE\xbd\xcbj\xeaB\x8aAoky+\x82,L\xa3\xeb\\7\xe4jT\xc9\x0eo\xaa\xfc\x9a\x14%Y\xb7u\x9e\x1d_b\xdbmaj\n[\x1f\x95\xbd\x05K*\xae\xb5\xe9g\xa6\x8d\x98Q\xbaa\x9c.\x14<bI\xe4\xa5\x89\xcf\xa0\x89ft\xa6\xb9\x10L', b'\xb0\x98\xael^\x9a\xd0\xa1\x19o\xf8\xf8 \x1c\xcfY\xdf\x19zdq\xbf\xac>P\x87\x17d\x1e\xc6\xe0\x0cE\x99_\xb8\x15\x06\xfd1\xf3\xb1\xab3\xfc%\x1d\x9a\xd33\x7f\x084\xeb\xf0\xf6\xad\xd2\xb8u\x196\xfe\xef\xaa\xda\xda\xe7a\xe8\xab:o\xf8[|\xe7]b\xffS\xdbK\xbej7nw\x83\xdf\x85\xd2c\xd6\xb2\xbbF\xdf\xb1\xf0u\xc9\x8b7_j\xdaG\x16\xf1\xcf\xacN\xcb\xb3\x0b#E\xfe\x0fi\x07\\1\x00\x00\x06\xf4\x00\x00\x1a\xccx\x9c\xddX\xdb\x8e\xdb6\x10}\xf7\x87\xe4\x89P\xc4\xab\xa4\xa2,\x90.\x9c\xa2\xa8\xdb-\xe2E\xd1\x87\x00\x82\xd6\xa2\xd7\xea\xca\x92!\xd2\xd9n\xd1\x8f\xefP\x17[\x971\x92<\xa6\xf6\xcak\xd1\xc3!g83\xe7\x8clp>\x9e\x8a\xc6\xd8 7\xfb\xec\\:\xed\x9a\xb3Y\xed\xea\xb2nl\xf0X\xd7\xcf\xe9\xc1d\xb9i\x82}\xdd\x98\xa7\xa6>W\xb9\x0e\xdb\xd7 \xb4;d\xd5\x13(\xa0c\x91\xf7\xedke\x8eYQ\x06u\x9e\xdb\xf4%s\xbb\x83\xdeg\xa55+W\xe7\xd9kPT\xbb\xf2\x9c\x9b\xf4\xa9\xc9\xaa<\xb5Y\x99\x1d\x8bny\xebu\xd8\xc0:\x93\x1d\xd3S\x99\xbd\xf6\xf3:uU\xed\x8a\x9d\xb1\xba\xbf=d\xe5\xde\x15G\xa3\x87\r\xf9\x81\xd4\x8f \x1b\xca\x0b\xeb\xf5\x05\xf6P\xbf\xa4.{6\xe9c\xb6{\xb6\xbd\xfe~\xddS\x01[-\xaa\xa7\xb43m\xea\x9ag\xf3\x9a\x1e\xebO&\xcdJ\xd38\xab\xb7\xe1GM\t\'\x92\xd0\x90PJ\xa8 \x14\xbe+B#\xc2B\xc2\x18a\x8a\xb0\x84\xf0\x90p\x90c\x84s\xc2\x13"(\x11\x8c\x08N\x84""!\x12\x14DD&D\x85D1\xa2b\x12\x85$\xa2$b$\xe2$\x12$\x8aH\x1c\x92\x98\x92\x98\x93X\x928&I\x02+r\xb8"X\xd6/\r\xdf\xfd\xca4&\x14\x96\xa1\xb0\x0e\x05\xcdT\xfa\r\xc1v$\x8c\x83j\xaa`\\\xc1\xbd\x8a\xfem\xb7*\x03\x98\x0c\xd7\xf0\t\xef\xa0\xbf\xc8oue\xba\x8f7[z\xdbN\xbfd\xf2\xc5\xd6FD\xc4_i3C\xccV\xbd\xe9\xecj:W\xde\xe4\xaf3\x8b\xfd?\xcd\xe2\xdf\x9eY\xed\xce\x07\xbb\xe4\r\xbb\xc47kW\x18Ho\xdd\xad\x03\x93\xdf\xaca\xc3\xb9\xe1\x96\xadr(\xd2Pp_\xa1\x9aw\xc5<h\xab5\r?~\x17\x86\xd9q(\xbaeQ\x99t\xc0\x92}QB=\xbf\x14k\xb3\xab\xab<k^{,J\xff:[W\xec\x8b]\xe6\x8a\xba\xd2w\xeb\xdf\x1e\xd6\x1f\xc6z\xce\xa7A\x05@\xc2\xf9X]\xd0-p\xb1\x0e\x97\x83\t6\xa8\xb0\xc1\x08\x06\x17\xe84[\xab\xc5\x96\xa7\xech\xd2\xea||4\xcd\x04R\xdb\xf1Sm\xdd\t\x9c\x93\x07\x1e}z\x84\x8a\xc2P\xb0x\x90;5\xa6\xd5\x11\x9c\xad\xe9\xd1\xa9\xff\xa5\xcc\xac\xeb5\x8f\xa7\xf3\xf6\xb5\xbabm`\x8b\x7f\x0cb\x83\x95\xb1VK\xac\x1c\xa9\xf2\xe8~w\x87LL\xb4\x88z\xd4\x9da\xe4\x14@\x07\x84\x1e\x0c\x9f\xfaP\xa0\x9b\x12\x9a/E%**5K\x96\xb2\x0c\x95U\x9a\xd2\xa5,Ge#M\xd5R6\xd4\x17\xaa\xd3S\xa1\x99\xab\xd4r\x01+C\xad\xd8R\x17E\x8c\xb4\x92j\x85m\x87i\xb9\xdc\x8e\x95\\\xb3hptc>\x15\xd6\xe4i\x1f\xf4\x9d\xc3\x97\t\xe7?\xacf\x90\x97\xc9\x9c\xb51\x84$-\xd6L\xf4\xd2\xdf6\xd2R\x0e\xfb\x00>\xd4T\xc5\xd3\xc1\xa5s\xee\xd4\xa5F/\xb6/\xaa\xac\xbc\x91\x996\xd6\x82\x7fV_gaG\xbd\x06\xea\xdaR0\xa8?\xf0F\xdc\xa5Y8\xc8\x0fL1h\xf9\x9b\xab\xe1\xef\x04\x93\x97\x93 h\xc40\xa9\xdds\xcf\xf2\xda%\xfa-^\x94]\xcc\x99\x92\xe1Q\x90$I\xcb\x97\x87r\x06\xff\xb3\xc7\x12\x8a]S@\x9ade:\xa4\xcb$\xcd\xc7\xdc{\xa4\xeb\xd6\x11qM\xa3\xe5\xa8\xd0b9H\xbd\xe8\xa9>\x9dO\x9f\xf3\xf3b*\xd3\xd7\n\xb5\xec\x0bn\xedMA\x80\xc7\xcbaH\x91h\xe5\xb2G\xef\xad\xb6\xfa\xbb\xd7\x93/X\xed\xd0\xd0\x1c\x9c\x9az\x88\xeb\x81yw', b'\xb7o\xae\xc4;\xf9z\xccT\xb7a\x13\xb8\x07E\xc0S%\x0b\xfc\x94\x18+\x0f;\x08\ro\xc1\xe8\x94\xc6\xf9\xab\x83\xfc\xeb}K\x14\xe0B\x1c\x19j*\xe7\xa1\x16"\xa1\xd66X\xd0\xdf<\xa6\xa5\xc9\x9e\xce\xe0\xb2\r%\x1bF6\xb0\x87\r\xb8f\x03>\xd8\xc2-\xdc\t\xb2\x81{\xf0\xd8\x86\xc1\x05\x8e\xd9\xc2\xa0$\x1b\x05\x03^P\x92-\x88\xc0O\xb0\xeb-\x8c\'\xf0-\x84\x0b\xf4Q\xaf\x10~\x04Go\x98Z\x01R5\xe9\xa7\xc2\xbc\x04\xa5\xa9\x9e\xdc\xe1Z7\xc7\x905\x8a\x97\xbb\xf65FF\xa4\xcb\x9c\xc1\xfa\xbcMm\x1dT\x9fL\x05k\xdbS\r\x19\xeb\x13\xc7G\xf8$\x8c\xb2<\x872\xe9\x97\xb8\x01J2\xc2 \x81+\xad$"\x8c\xb1\x08\xcb#\x1d-s\xd0I\xcf.\x86\xdc\xf7\xe1<\xb0\x98[\xf8\xcccM\x93>A\xbf,-y\xa2c\x84\xacH\x14\xe68\xd3\x11\x02\x89\x12\x85e\xceu\x84\xe12\n\xcc\\h\x95\xcc\x1b\xe4\xc0T\xbe\xda\xe5\x93\xce~\xc4Rn\xf04\x89\xd1/\xcb\xa5\x8e\xb1\xbd\x87WZv\xa9\x1275STs\xa8\xa3e\xadt\x12e\x15\x9c\xeaH\xf5D\x08"\xf6\x98A<\x9a\xbf\xdd\xdb\x83;\x96\x13\xa2\xd7\x03\x1eV"\'$o\x94\xc1\xebh\x1d\x85l\x9e\xe4^\xc0#\xd6H\xb0C\x8b\xde\xc9c\xb4\xefc>\xd7\x93\xccZb\xc8\xfc\xa0\x86\\)\xaa.Q\xfag5>\x8d\xf8\xa4@/a\x06\x98\x13R\xe0\x05\x04r\xb8\xc0K4\x83\xafs\x12\x8d\xf1)\xc15O\xaen\xbb$\x11\xfeXj6\x17\xa8e\xdc\x9f\x16\xd4\x01`\x0c\x16\xa1\x1fBj\x89\xb0\x1c\xa14G\xe2B\x85h\xcb\x80\x86\x96\x08\xb5\x88\xd1\n0\xedc6\xeb\xf7\x0f\xc8l\xaa\xc5\xc5\xf2y\'4>\xd5w\xedk\xf6l\xedsu\xcf\n\x80t\x8a\xb44\xc3)M8\xc9\x15rn\x86t\x1b\xf6\xd6e\x8d\x9bv7@\x93\x13\x8eT\x12\x8e\xf5^\x96\xc6\x9a#t\x86B\x03\xa2\xd0\x95:\xc7\xd8\x81=\xb0I\xbc\xee\xeb\xcau\xdd\x10E89Gk\x19\x85\xa0AN\x98\xa3e\x89J\xcd1\xcd(\xa6P\xa5\x19\xd2fp\x14Sh\xa49\xd6\xbf\xa0\x81F\x81\x1e \xb2h\t\xa3\x10VH\\s\x0f\x19c\xe6{)\xdf\xdb\xf0\xcdv\t\x85\x96B\xfc\xb0Kp\x8f\x91\rs\x08\x8a1\x14r\xfbr\xaaY\xe9\x80\x92f\x0e)\x8c\xc9z\xfd\x9ec5`$\x14\x87\xef\xf8\x1d\xe6\x84q\xbev\xff\xd3\x97"w\xd0%\x1b\xd7\xedW\xa9Y\xee@Eo\xb2Q\xee,\xb0\xabo\xb7\xc6\x8f\x94s\xd8\xf9\x88\xc8\xcf\xd8s\xa2#9\xe5%\xfb\xb3;7\x97\x19\xd3\xf5\x81N\x15\xc6\x02\x03\x9e\xf4\xd2\xc8C\x04\xe41\xf7\xa2\x05l\xcf\xb4oa\x08\x12\xd8\x02\rl\x06E\x11IZ\x81\x066SZb\x9a\xe3+\x11\xbc\x00\xde\x90\xaf\x1c+\xd8\x0c\x88\x14\x12=\x02-\x15,\xd6\x11\xb6\xaa\x8fz\x7f\xaeA{\xcc\x10\x18\xd8\\\xaa%\xc2\xd8\x04\xca\x9b\x18\xd3\x02\xdb\x15\x1a\xd3\x8ck\x81\x84\xa1@k\r\x13Z\xd2\x95\x07\xc7Q\x89\xf5\xe5g\xda\xe7\x8eRq&L\xd1Z%|\xccO\x05\x19.\x88V\x13\x06[\xb84\xe4\xe3P\xeax\xd5$\x8c\xe7\xa92(ks\xa2\xbf\x81xv\xe7S\xfaX\x9e\x9b\xc7I\x1b?~\xf2wi\xb4W\xab\xd5\xf7o\xb7\xc69 \xbf\xf6\x87\xd5v\xfd\xe1\x8f\x9f\xef\xd6+\xba\xfa\xf5\xdd\x9f\xe9\xf6\xf7\xfb\x0f\x0f\xdb\x1f\xef\xef\x7f\xd9\xa6\x0f\xf7\xe9O\xeb\x87\x15\x10\x8d\xff\x00\xc6Z\x92\xd6', b'\x00\x00\x02m\x00\x00 \x00x\x9c\xadY\xc1j[A\x0c\xbc\xfb+\x8c\xcf\x81\xeeJ\xbb\xd2>Hr\t=\x14J[\x9a\xdcC\xd2:&\xc4\xc4\xe0\xe0\xffoRhK\x9f\x97\xec \xcf\xf1\x850\x91\xb4\xa3\x91F\xf9\xf6\xf5\xd3\x97\x9b\x8f\xdf\xaf\x17\xadMy:\x13\x9d\xdc\xce&\xd3\x92\x17\xe7\x9f\xd7w\x9b\xc3\xfaj\xb7\xdd\xed_.\xff\xfb\\\xbe\x1c\xee\xb7\xbf?o\x1f\x7f^\xacrZ-\x1fv\xfb\xf5f\xbf;<\xbf}\x9b\xbbK\xae\xab\xe5\xfd\xdd\x8f\xa7??m*\x9a\\V\xcb\x0f\xef\x82\x890\xc1\x14\x01KC\x98\x82\xc0d\xf1!Pe&7!`*5\x0f\xa1\x14z\xc1a\x9d4\x93\xea\xa4\x10\t\x10\xa0v\x0cd\x93\xa5H\x8d:\xe5>\x86\x1a\xd6\xa8tjt\x0c\x03R\xa0t\xea\x14\x07\x83X\x8e\x82\xcd\x98>\x0b\xe9_\xa0\x03\x18c\xc6\x04\x91Aj\x1d\x02AT\x00\xe8Y;z\x10~\xbf\xdaI/\xd44\x95\x95\x9eud%\xd02\x06\xb5\x0c\x12\x0f\xc4p\x15{\xeb\xf5\x01\x94\xd3\x84\xc5\xa0w\x03I`\xd0P\x00j\xe5\xcc\xa1\xee\xd0\xdcC\xa2\x82j5dT\xc6t\x05\x08(c]\x07\xd6)\xf7Z/\x16\x97uV\x9f\xb0\xb4\xe4y\xe7\x04\xe5\\R\xa7\xee\x01E\x90\xd4i\xbf\xf8"\x95\xa0\xc1\x00\xa3Ao\x88\xa2q\x97\xeb\xcc\x92R\xe9\xad\xb2A\x01|\xfd\x1d\xda~\r-\x8e\x90\xc2\x8b\xb1\x96P1\x96\xda\x08MH\xa5qV~i4o\xd4\xa0\xdc\x80\x88 m\x00\xcc\x0cd\x1e\x11\x13\x929\x99\xa90\xb5@1\xd3\x07\xa3A\x1c\x1f\xe7\xa8Le\xd7\x9eA\x8a\xbd!\xd5\x1d\xe9\xdc\x1e\x9d\x10\x17K[\xb4g\x8f\xe2\x19V*\xbb\xaaQ\xf6\x0f\xa5n\xb5%\t%\xaa\x92 \xa5\x81fi\xc1x\x8aa\xcd\xab~\xc2\x8c/\x98\xf7B+\xef\x9c\xc3^q\x8ej\x15\xcc\x97`\x95j\xcc\x0bhiP\xa5\xd0\x13Cb\x1e0k\xcf\r\xc4\xd12\xb3n\xd5\xa1\x9dt\xc8\x8c\x8a1\x15u\xf7\x89\xd9E\xd6\xbb\xb5\x87}\x8f)\x14\xdb\xf8\xda\xa3\xcc\xa3\x98ag[\x14\x8d\xba\x05\x186q\xc7\x15\xc3\xfc\x13v\x8c\xe2^\xa3\xb0s\x14\x8a6\x9f\xde\xc1yk\xf3\xde\x0e\xe30\x15\xc7\x9c\xca\xad\xf9d\x0b\xe7\x08N6\xc0Q;\xb6\xe7\x0ccr\xec\xfa\x03\xf1\xdd\xb1k\r\x86\xd5\xbb\xae\xc4\xce\x9c\x99\xe5\xaa\x1d\xf3\x9e`~\x13\x85S\xaf\x7f\x9e\x84\xc3\x9c\xad.\xccm\xc4\x95\x1a\x1b\xf5\xff`^\xfe\xf6\xcf/u\x1b\xf5\xfc\x00\x00\x01u\x00\x00\x10\x9dx\x9c\xad\x97\xc1j\xc30\x10D\xef\xfe\n\xe3\x1f\x88\xb4+\xaddhsIM{\xc8\xad\xed9$\xad\x13JC\r\x0e\xfe\xff6\x81\x96\x92\x084\xc8{\xb4\xb1\x1f\xd2hv\xb4;L_\xef\xf7\x8d\x95\x10\x02Y\xdf\xd4\xbb\xed\xdb\xe7a\x1c.o#\x13\x9b@M\xbdXVw\xeb~{\x98\xfa\xd5p\x1c\xc6\xfa4\xed\x8e\x97\xc7\xcd\xc7\xcfg\xc1\xc5\xa6\xde\x0fc\xff\xfb\xdf<Z`\x84f)\xe4IN\x8d\xe4\xb5H\x11"1y\x9bW\xaamoY\xd2\x8a)\xd2=\x9a\x84\xee\xb74`\x8f\xd1@\xba\xc3\xeb\x82\x14Ci6 \xbb\x84\xf4\x8f\x16\xf2\xbd\xc9s\x12\xe7X\xc2!\xab\xc4!M\xc5\t\xaag\x98\x06y\x0b;?\x82\xbc\x808\x9e4\x130\x12\xe4\x07\x94\xc6\x06SL\xb8\xcd\xb3 g\xe4\x1d\xc6\x90\'\xb0Sd\xad\x94\x8f\xac\x9a4,\xaa\xb4\x84Wg\xd0\x12~-\xbf9X)\xbf\x1c\xe4TtU\x0eJC\x98\xa6\x9ab.\xe1\xb4r\xfd]\xc2i3hP*\xc24\xd5,\xf3W\x0e\xb9\x8e\xea\xbf\xa5\xe68\xaa\x95\xeeU+\xdd+u\x15^Uy\x81j\x13IYQ\xeaR\x84t\xbc \xaa\x95-\xaa\xbd\xaf@\xce\x82TW\xbd?D\xf5\xfe\x08\xaaI\x1dT\xbbW\xb5\x192\xc6D\x05\x95k\x96\x9a\xfd\n;\xa865\x13%;D\x97\xad\xa6\x16\x9b\x89\x98\xc2\xd9Bg\xd6\xe2\x1f\xec\xb4\xac\x1e\xbb\x97\xcd\xf3\xea\xa9{x]w\xd57\x19\xa5%b']
```

And here is how I get it via sockets:

```
DBS_HOST = '66.66.66.66'
DBS_PORT = 4451
socket_use = None

def connect_todbs():
    global socket_use
    socket_use = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket_use.settimeout(5)
    print("Connecting to Server")
    socket_use.connect((DBS_HOST, DBS_PORT))

def run_dbs():
    data = []
    connect_todbs()
    time.sleep(1)

    print("Sending credentials:")
    socket_use.send("SO\n".encode())
    socket_use.send("more data\n".encode())
    socket_use.send("more data\n".encode())

    # wait for data:
    print("Getting Data:")
    try:
        while True:
            datachunk = socket_use.recv(1024)
            if not datachunk:
                break 
            data.append(datachunk)  # .decode() will raise an error as the data encoding dont match
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    print("Closing Connection:")
    socket_use.close()
    print("Received Data:")
    print(data)

    return
```

And here is just a lazy check if its and encoding issue:

```
all_codecs = ['ascii', 'big5', 'big5hkscs', 'cp037', 'cp273', 'cp424', 'cp437', 'cp500', 'cp720', 'cp737', 'cp775', 'cp850', 'cp852', 'cp855', 'cp856', 'cp857', 'cp858', 'cp860', 'cp861', 'cp862', 'cp863', 'cp864', 'cp865', 'cp866', 'cp869', 'cp874', 'cp875', 'cp932', 'cp949', 'cp950', 'cp1006', 'cp1026', 'cp1125', 'cp1140', 'cp1250', 'cp1251', 'cp1252', 'cp1253', 'cp1254', 'cp1255', 'cp1256', 'cp1257', 'cp1258', 'euc_jp', 'euc_jis_2004', 'euc_jisx0213', 'euc_kr', 'gb2312', 'gbk', 'gb18030', 'hz', 'iso2022_jp', 'iso2022_jp_1', 'iso2022_jp_2', 'iso2022_jp_2004', 'iso2022_jp_3', 'iso2022_jp_ext', 'iso2022_kr', 'latin_1', 'iso8859_2', 'iso8859_3', 'iso8859_4', 'iso8859_5', 'iso8859_6', 'iso8859_7', 'iso8859_8', 'iso8859_9', 'iso8859_10', 'iso8859_11', 'iso8859_13', 'iso8859_14', 'iso8859_15', 'iso8859_16', 'johab', 'koi8_r', 'koi8_t', 'koi8_u', 'kz1048', 'mac_cyrillic', 'mac_greek', 'mac_iceland', 'mac_latin2', 'mac_roman', 'mac_turkish', 'ptcp154', 'shift_jis', 'shift_jis_2004', 'shift_jisx0213', 'utf_32', 'utf_32_be', 'utf_32_le', 'utf_16', 'utf_16_be', 'utf_16_le', 'utf_7', 'utf_8', 'utf_8_sig']

def try_to_decode():
    test = target_data[0]
    for j in all_codecs:
        try:
            print("To ", j, "\n", test.decode(j))
        except:
            print("To ", j, " FAILED!\n")
            pass
```

ANY IDEAS????

Than you.

Comment: where is your code? What result do you see in console, What result do you expect? Text `get nothing` is the most useless information. We can't run your code, we can't see your screen, and we can't read in your mind - so we have not clue to help you. You have to add all details in question ( not in comments)

Comment: frankly, I don't know what you expect. Socket data is never `human readable string`. Eventually you may get byte-after-byte and convert to hex/dec/oct/bin string and display this string. ie. `for char in data["Raw"]["load"]: print(hex(ord(char)), end=' ')`. But `raw-loade` seems like someone try convert it to string and it has big mess instead of original value.

Comment: @furas thank you for your comment I edited my question and added more data on what I'm trying to do / understand - The goal is easy I'm trying to read the stream after a connection is established but no matter what I do I cant decode / decompress this data to expected XML format -> this is why I tried to capture the raw packets and tried to understand what I'm missing....

Comment: as for me `raw data` has all headers `Ethernet`, `IP`, `TCP`, and some part of stream. You have to get many packages to get all stream data. But if server uses some compressing then first you would have to know what compression it uses, and next decompress it. Without this information you can't get data. If server uses HTTP protocol then it may use compression `gzip` or [brotli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli). But if server uses HTTP then it is simpler to use module `requests` it should automatically decompress it.